# Refused to get json from Url because Content Security Policy directive 'connect-src'

Tags: ajax, datatables, content-security-policy

I'm trying to do an ajax call on a local api and it wont let me (same server, different URL and using Curl works just fine)

> Refused to connect to
>   'http://lambda/ManagedDataWebServices/api/NyMods/ModSearch/OPTIONS%20INFORMATION%20TECHNOLOGY%20LLC?_=1572571626624'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that
>   'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

This is the code I'm using:

```
      let url = "http://lambda/ManagedDataWebServices/api/NyMods/ModSearch/"+$("#nameorcombo").val();
       tabledom = $('#table').DataTable( {
          "dom": 'lBfrtip',
          "dataType" : "json",
           "crossDomain": "true",
            "ajax": {
                "url": url,
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                     }
                 });
```

tried different meta tags with no luck, am I missing something? (The server is IIS)

Comment: Add `http:` or something to the policy. `default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` allows `https://lambda/ManagedDataWebServices/api/NyMods/ModSearch/` (https) but not `http://lambda/ManagedDataWebServices/api/NyMods/ModSearch/` (http).

Comment: tried this   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"> but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting the "faulty" directive specifically: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *">`

[default-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) is a fallback for some directives such as `connect-src` so if you specify `connect-src` it should take precedence over `default-src`.

On a side note, this `default-src`directive is way too lax, almost useless.